# How can I test a final class with private constructor?

Tags: java, unit-testing

How can I test a class like this (see code below)?

```
public final class A {

    public static final String FIRST = "1st";
    public static final String SECOND = "2nd";

    private A() {
        // NOP
    }
}
```

For now all my coverage tools say that constructor isn't covered with tests. My tests look like on this:

```
assertEquals(A.FIRST, "1st");
assertEquals(A.SECOND, "2nd");
```

How can I test my class?

*UPD*

This code solved my problem.

```
@Test
public void magic() throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Constructor<A> constructor = A.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    A instance = constructor.newInstance();

    assertNotNull(instance);
}
```

Yes, I agree that this isn't the best solution. But it works :)

Comment: Why would you want to test what is essentially a NOP method?

Comment: I need it because of coverage. I need 100% of coverage. But Cobertura, Jacoco, and my InelliJ IDEA  tools say that class in uncovered.

Comment: You are using a class only to put constants on it. Don't you have any better place to set thoses? It's really a strange case

Comment: I don't want to use an enum.

Comment: @barbara That is not a good use of your time! And I think you can set those to ignore empty methods.

Comment: Things like this, and other trivial-type methods, are why people rarely ask for 100% coverage.

Comment: Wanting 100% code coverage is probably more to _known who has the biggest_ (which is not what testing and code coverage are meant to), than to help maintainability and reduce bugs.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19106976/technique-for-extending-a-class-with-private-constructors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reflection is probably the way to go: [How do I test a class that has private methods, fields or inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571/how-to-test-a-class-that-has-private-methods-fields-or-inner-classes)

By the way, this is possibly a duplicate of the question in the link provided.

Alternatively, could you create a wrapper method that is `protected` which simply forwards all calls to the `private` method?

Comment: Okay, then I think that reflection is likely your best bet.

Comment: You mean that I need to create an instance of A class with Reflection API and check this instance?