# Java iterate over Iterable<Text> values and add them to a list of distinct values

Tags: java, list, getter, iterable

I have an Iterable object called values (Iterable values), and I want to add them to a list of distinct elements.

```
for (Text val : values) {
    if (!mylist.contains(val)) {
                mylist.add(val);
    }
}
```

It onlu adds one element to this list. If I remove that condition to check for distinctness, I see that all the elements are repeated.

I have tried many things, I thought maybe I should use a .get() method like this

```
for (Text val : values) {
    if (!mylist.contains(val.get())) {
                mylist.add(val.get());
    }
}
```

but then Java gives this error, that symbol val not found:

```
>editorPairs.java:67: cannot find symbol
>symbol  : method get()
>location: class org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>                    mylist.add(val.get());
>                                  ^
>1 error
```

The full code is below:

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        List<Text> mylist = new ArrayList<Text>();

        for (Text val : values) {
            if (!mylist.contains(val)) {
                mylist.add(val);
            }
        }

        if(mylist.size() > 1) {
            int size = mylist.size();
            for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
                Text t1 = mylist.get(i);
                context.write(t1, t1);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not use a `Set`? Also, `context.write(t1, t1);` is supposed to do what?

Comment: I tried set too, but it also happens with Set as well. I know that set can only contains distinct values, but in my hadoop program, the outputs were the same.

Answer (score 1):

We need to use `[Set][1]` to get the distinct values as `[set][1]` doesn't add the value if it already exists (hence, no need to check for `contains()`). Now, to allow set to determine the unique values, we need to override `equals()` and `hashCode()` method in our class (`Text` in our case).

[This](http://www.java2novice.com/java-collections-and-util/hashset/duplicate/) example explains what needs to be done.

Comment: Based on your suggestion, I guess maybe this class Text (defined in Hadoop) is not inherited from a Comparable class. I will convert the Text values to string and try see what happens.

Comment: In that case, if we know the contents of Text class then we can define our own `comparator` and use `TreeSet` to store the values as explained here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880450/java-hashset-with-a-custom-equality-criteria.

Answer (score 0):

the better thing to do is to use a set.

instantiate a HashSet that use equals method of your object to add values only if distint.